# Combine each element from Array 1 with each element from Array 2

Tags: c#

I'll keep this simple. My dataset is as follows:

Array 1:

```
James
Bob
Jim
```

Array 2:

```
0
1
2
```

I want to create a new array by joining the two arrays so they produce something like the following:

```
James 0
James 1
James 2
Bob 0
Bob 1
Bob 2
Jim 0
Jim 1
Jim 2
```

How can it be done in C#. I've came into this problem before, I remember using extension methods but I have no idea what area of Set Theory this falls under.

Comment: What is the type of your result array, `string[]`?

Comment: i guess first array is string and second is int and like tim asked what is the result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use a cross join (Cartesian product):

```
var result = from x in array1
             from y in array2
             select string.Format("{0} {1}", x, y);
```

See it live: http://ideone.com/1TdKGy

Comment: Usually the term "full outer join" is used for something else, and this is called ___cross join___.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for a cross product:

```
from a in a1
from b in a2
select new { a, b }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need Cartesian Join or Cross Join. One more way to do it using `SelectMany`:

```
var arr1 = new string [] {"James","Bob","Jim"};
var arr2 = new int [] { 1, 2, 3};

var query = arr1.SelectMany(x => arr2, (x, y) => new { x, y });

foreach(var item in query)
{
  Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to go:

```
            string[] names = { "James", "Bob", "Jim" };
            int[] numbers = { 0, 1, 2 };
            string[] result = new string[names.Length * 3];
            for (int i = 0, y = 0 ; i < result.Length; i+=3,y++)
            {
                result[i] = names[y] + numbers[0].ToString();
                result[i + 1] = names[y] + numbers[1].ToString();
                result[i + 2] = names[y] + numbers[2].ToString();
            }
```